# How many consecutive forced moves are possible in chess?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, chess

The question concerns chess. I call a move *forced* if, in a given position, is the unique move consistent with the rules of the game. I wonder what is the largest integer $n$ such that there exists a legal position in which:

1. both black and white have forced moves for $n$ consecutive times;
2. the position is never repeated (with the same color having to move).

Notice that without condition 2., the answer is $\infty$.

Comment: Are you restricting attention to the usual 8x8 board, or do you permit arbitrarily large (perhaps even infinite) boards?

Comment: I was thinking to an 8x8 board.

Comment: I think another problem is whether position may be achieved in a game (similar questions might be asked about lot of chess stackexchange positions).

Comment: @IgorSikora In the chess problem world, it is a standard convention that positions must be reachable in an actual game (i.e., "legal"), unless there is an explicit warning that the position is, or might be, illegal. Amateurs might not be aware of this convention, but anything published in a chess problem journal is expected to follow this convention. If it doesn't, that's akin to publishing a theorem in a professional mathematics journal with a fatally incorrect proof. It can happen, but it's not supposed to.

Comment: @TimothyChow Good to know, I wasn't aware of this convention. However, a lot of solutions in chess.SE miss this condition then, or at least miss a proof that the condition is satisfied. For example in the link that you are giving a lot of solutions cannot be achieved in a real game.

Comment: @IgorSikora Which ones cannot be achieved in a real game? I don't see any at first glance. Unless you're referring to dead reckoning?

Comment: @TimothyChow for example this position: https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/4967/24735 It seems unlikely to me to achieve such position in a game. However, I am not making hard claim - rather I miss a written game (even theoretical, i.e. with moves such that no reasonable player would play them) that proves that this position might occur. On the side, are there any software which takes as an input a position and gives as an output a game that finishes in this position?

Comment: @IgorSikora That one isn't hard to figure out; e.g., if it's White to move now, then White's last move might have been h5xg6+ with Black responding Kh7-h6. More generally, what you're asking for is a *proof game*. There's a whole genre of chess problems where you're presented with a position and told that (for example) it's the position after Black's 10th move, and your job is to reconstruct the entire game. One program for solving such problems is [Natch](http://natch.free.fr/Natch.html). But I'm not sure how well Natch works for positions like this one where the solution is far from unique.

Comment: But as for your main concern, chess problems aren't usually accompanied by proof games because if all you care about is legality, then an experienced chess problem solver can usually figure out quickly whether a given position is legal, unless the position has been specifically designed to be challenging. (Of course, there is an entire genre of problems, namely *classical retros*, where the point is to deduce some nontrivial fact about the past history of the game. I've composed a couple such problems myself; see the final two positions on [my webpage](http://timothychow.net/fun.html).)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This question has been answered at [chess.stackexchange.com](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/4963/). It seems that if you allow promoted pieces, the current record is $n=9$.

Comment: The fellow who found that solution, Karl Scherer, has come up several times on mathoverflow, in connection with dissection problems.

Comment: Wow, I didn't even know that there is a chess stack exchange website... (and I am a chess player!). I accepted the answer, although this just shows the current empirical record, not a theoretical bound. I guess the latter is very difficult to achieve...

Comment: This still doesn't show a theoretical answer, but I think the top answer on this [chess.stackexchange.com](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/33904) question I asked recently contains a longer sequence than the current accepted answer.

Comment: @HymnsForDisco But there the moves are not quite forced, e.g. black has many options for the first move (albeit all strategically equivalent).

Comment: @HymnsForDisco What Will Sawin said. If you scroll down far enough in the list of answers to the question I posted a link to, you'll see that Rewan Demontay posted his position there, too.

Comment: No need to scroll when you can link directly to answers!  I think the relevant ones are [$n = 9$](https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/4965); and the [top answer](https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/33905) to @HymnsForDisco's [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/390622/how-many-consecutive-forced-moves-are-possible-in-chess#comment995854_390632).  But all(?) the answers are by RD, so I'm not sure which of them is the one @‍TimothyChow is [referencing](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/390622/how-many-consecutive-forced-moves-are-possible-in-chess#comment995864_390632).

Comment: @LSpice The [$n=9$](https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/15255/) example was posted by Hauke Reddmann (but later edited by Rewan Demontay; perhaps that has caused confusion). Rewan Demontay's [answer](https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/24148/) shows several positions; the one [I was referencing](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/390622/how-many-consecutive-forced-moves-are-possible-in-chess/390632#comment995864_390632) was the 4th diagram (attributed to Alexey Khanyan), which is the same as the 1st position in [his answer to Hymns for Disco's question](https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/33905).

Comment: @LSpice The position by Alexey Khanyan has $n=11$ but it does not satisfy the condition that A. DellaCorte wanted.

Comment: @LSpice Oh, wait, I see now that it was not only Hauke Reddmann who posted Karl Scherer's $n=9$ example; Rewan Demontay did as well. Confusing indeed. Anyway, hopefully everything is clear now.